# Natural language toolkit

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk, helper

The function `nltk.download()` returns this:

> Error connecting to server: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established  connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`

I'm unable to solve this error? How do I need to solve this one?

I've tried installing NLTK and then downloading its data but failed to do it since it is showing `Win Error 10060 - error connecting to server` even when I have good server connection.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/11286032)